# Private static variables to establish invariants

Tags: c++

Is it reasonable to use private static variables to establish invariants in your class?

Ex:

```
class MovingObject
{
public:
    //...Stuff
private:
    // Invariants
    static const double VELOCITY; // Moving objects always move at this velocity
    // etc. for any other invariants
    //...
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "MovingObject.h"
// Invariants
const double MovingObject::VELOCITY = 256.5;
//etc.
```

Comment: An interesting article regarding the topic.
http://www.stanford.edu/~pgbovine/programming-with-rep-invariants.htm

Comment: Just a quick suggestion - don't make your constant names all uppercase. By convention in C and C++, all uppercase symbols tend to be used for preprocessor macros. Pretty much any serious C & C++ developer I know has spent countless hours trying to track down a compilation issue that was caused by the preprocessor mangling an uppercase C++ symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. This is a common idiom across several OO languages including Java.

Comment: Thanks. I ask because I was reading about possible issues that may occur if you try multi-threading with statics.

Comment: The MT issues with statics in C++ mostly show up when you're both reading and writing to them. You've already declared `VELOCITY`const which implies that you're only reading from it. Read access from multiple threads is fine as long as nothing potentially changes them from underneath you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though those are generally called 'constants'.  See the article anon linked for a discussion of 'invariant' as it's generally used in object-oriented design.